# Convolution bluring image - python

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

I have this code below which is almost working - only thing I need here is the output of the convolution has to be devided by 9 and rounded down. Is this somehow possible with convolve2d?

```
import scipy
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np

def boxBlur(image):
    matrix = np.array(image)
    W = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1]])
    np.pad(matrix, 1, mode='constant')
    return scipy.signal.convolve2d(matrix, W, mode='valid')
```

So for this example:

```
boxBlur([[1,1,1],[1,7,1],[1,1,1]])
```

The output right now is [[15]] but it should be [[1]] (15/9=1,6666 rounded down=1)

Is there a way to not only use the convolve image on the matrix, but also do something else.

Right now the way I managed the problem is to manually go over the array and devide every cell by 9 rounding it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called uniform filtetring, hence use SciPy's [`uniform_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html), which should be faster as well -

```
from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter

uniform_filter(image.astype(float))[1:-1,1:-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [38]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: image = np.random.randint(0,9,(7,7))

In [39]: boxBlur(image)/9.0
Out[39]: 
array([[4.55555556, 5.        , 5.55555556, 5.44444444, 5.11111111],
       [4.44444444, 5.        , 5.        , 4.88888889, 4.22222222],
       [4.33333333, 4.44444444, 3.44444444, 3.44444444, 3.77777778],
       [2.22222222, 2.55555556, 2.88888889, 3.44444444, 3.55555556],
       [2.44444444, 2.11111111, 2.44444444, 3.55555556, 4.33333333]])

In [40]: uniform_filter(image.astype(float))[1:-1,1:-1]
Out[40]: 
array([[4.55555556, 5.        , 5.55555556, 5.44444444, 5.11111111],
       [4.44444444, 5.        , 5.        , 4.88888889, 4.22222222],
       [4.33333333, 4.44444444, 3.44444444, 3.44444444, 3.77777778],
       [2.22222222, 2.55555556, 2.88888889, 3.44444444, 3.55555556],
       [2.44444444, 2.11111111, 2.44444444, 3.55555556, 4.33333333]])
```

Timings -

```
In [42]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: image = np.random.randint(0,9,(7000,7000))

In [43]: %timeit boxBlur(image)/9.0
1 loop, best of 3: 2.11 s per loop

In [44]: %timeit uniform_filter(image.astype(float))[1:-1,1:-1]
1 loop, best of 3: 612 ms per loop
```

---

**Rounding down**

For rounding it down, with the original solution, it would be : `boxBlur(image)//9`. The equivalent one here would be with *floor*-ing, so use `np.floor()`, but that might have precision issues. So, we might instead use `np.round` with a given number of decimal places for the precision and then floor with `.astype(int)` -

```
n = 10 # number of decimal places for precision
np.around(uniform_filter(image.astype(float))[1:-1,1:-1], decimals=n).astype(int)
```

For an input with ints, another way could be to scale up by `9` and round and then floor -

```
np.round(uniform_filter(image.astype(float))[1:-1,1:-1]*9)//9
```

Comment: @DominikLemberger Because the output is of float dtype. So, convert to int dtype with `.astype(int)`.

Comment: @DominikLemberger `out = np.floor(uniform_filter(image.astype(float))[1:-1,1:-1]).astype(int)`?

Comment: ok got it ... i have to put the .astype on the np.floor because the floor operation makes it float again

Comment: np.floor(uniform_filter(np.array(image).astype(float))[1:-1, 1:-1]).astype(int) tried it with this code and all unit tests are ok except for this one:
image: [[208,99,59,136,161,6,219,192,85,49], 
 [194,105,43,254,153,225,171,197,1,154], 
 [221,178,119,169,134,7,76,61,99,22], 
 [161,254,172,12,174,200,216,107,109,109]]

expected output: [[136,129,136,138,128,128,122,95], 
 [160,145,136,147,150,140,115,95]]

ouput: [[136,129,136,138,128,128,122,95], 
 [160,145,136,147,150,139,115,95]]

Comment: 225 + 171 + 197 + 7 + 76 + 61 + 200 + 216 + 107 = 1260 / 9 = 140 not 139

Comment: thanks for the round option - works for all unit tests and I reported a bug on the numpy github as there should be no problem with full integers and .floor ... because there is no need to round anything even once